# Custom ClaimsPrincipal in Asp.Net 5 (Mvc 6)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I override the default `Context.User` of type `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal` in Asp.Net 5 (MVC-6)?

I would like to use my customized User-type, so that it's accessible in Controllers (`HttpContext.User`), as well as in the Razor views (`@User.`)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is don't - it's generally a bad idea to try to implement your own security code; there's lots of options out there that will save you a lot of time up front, and save you a lot of headaches on the back side, too.

The other answer is that you can't - it's built in to the new framework [from the beginning.](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/4347ddfd0f7b97675ee0e4e489d69e42c6e29081/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs)

This is what a User POCO model is for. The Identity framework has operated this way (I think since the beginning), and it mirrors OAuth and most other authentication/authorization systems. It's an incredibly flexible and efficient model.

Instead what I would recommend doing is build your own `ClaimTypes` and use those in addition to the [ones built in to the framework.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Depending on how you're authenticating the user, you should be able to add them when you would create the `IPrincipal`, anyway.

Comment: This is untrue. There is a whole section dedicated to creating your own authentication scheme, and even provide you a way of using the cookie middleware to integrate your auth tokens (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html). The Identity Framework is very heavy and comes with everything-in (roles, permission etc.) which is often inappropriate for the system at hand. Let alone its assumptions and lack of support for modern, phone-number based authentication which you have to bend around the framework to pull off etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand, @Marchy. It looks like the link provided uses the existing `ClaimsPrincipal`, not overriding it, and, while it doesn't use the EF Identity framework plugins (which I was not advocating), it does use the pieces that @mikal was requesting to override. If I'm mistaken, maybe you could provide your own answer to the question?

Comment: @MattDeKrey At a first look, one could implement a `CustomClaimsPrincipal` similar to [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/08/custom-claims-principals-in-net-4-5/) in order to hide all that has/find/get claims machinery. Have that principal injected in place of the regular one (don't know how, in some filter or through auth framework provided hook). Then in every Controller you can cast `this.User` back to your `CustomClaimsPrincipal` and grab properties in a type safety way. Why is it a bad idea? Thanks

Comment: It's a bad idea to implement your own security code because, ultimately, there's been tons of effort put into the testing of the way ClaimsPrincipal is instantiated and created, and unless you're a Microsoft-sized company, you won't match that. As mentioned in the link in @superjos's comment, you can use ClaimTypes for storing your new info, but I'd suggest using extension methods to both avoid inheritance and avoid overriding the security code provided by the framework itself... all of that without using the Identity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - assign custom `.User` to `HttpContext` in middleware.

Long answer: [Where to set custom ClaimsPrincipal for all HttpRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337045/where-to-set-custom-claimsprincipal-for-all-httprequests)