# Extend the ClaimsPrincipal and ClaimsIdentity classes in MVC-6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to figure this thing out for a few days now, but have to turn to you guys (again).

As the title says, I would like to implement my custom ClaimsPrincipal and ClaimsIdentity, so that I can attach a few more properties to my Identity-instance.

I have done this earlier in MVC-5, using Global.asax.cs and an inherited  BaseController. In MVC-6 it seems like startup.cs would be the entry point for this, but I can't figure it out.

These are my two classes:

```
public class BaseIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid OrgId { get; set; }
    public string OrgName { get; set; }

    public BaseIdentity()
    {
    }
}
```

And..

```
public class BasePrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    private readonly BaseIdentity _identity;

    public BasePrincipal(BaseIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public new BaseIdentity Identity
    {
        get { return _identity; }
    }
}
```

How can I use these classes, instead of the default, when creating / retrieving Auth cookie?

There is a method called `IApplicationBuilder.UseClaimsTransformation()` , but can't find any documentation on how to use it - if it's even for this scenario?

Help much appreciated at this point! :)

BTW:  I would like to point out that I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292985/custom-claimsprincipal-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6) a week ago, when I first encountered this challenge. I got an answer, but this is something that I really have to fix, to make my website usable on MVC-6.

Comment: How are you creating an auth cookie currently? Your `Claim` properties from the raw `ClaimsIdentity` should be encoded there, and then you can add extension methods to pull out your values; `GetUserId` is already available via the Identity framework, for example.

Comment: Hmm. Do you mean that I should store values like OrganizationId  as a claim instead?

I might have to redesign the database a bit for that, as I've got a foreign key in User-table as reference to an Organization in my current design. But yeah, maybe claims could be used instead - though, I figure a bit slower?

Comment: You shouldn't need to redesign your database; Roles are likewise normalized in a database but get stored as `Claim`s in the `ClaimsIdentity`.

Comment: Hmm,ok. I haven't used claims in the past, so I'm kind of new to this approach. But, do I understand you correctly in that you would save the OrganizationId as a claim, and then use extension methods on the ClaimsPrincipal class, to fetch the OrganizationId in your code?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean! For reference, you can find Microsoft's `GetUserId` here: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/ab43154577fe126ef531bb7a11b5eaa03add7bbf/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/PrincipalExtensions.cs#L35-42

Answer (score 11):

I've done this using extension methods instead of inheritance.

```
public static class PrincipalExtensions
{
    public static string GetEmployeeNumber(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        return claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue("EmployeeNumber");
    }
}
```